# Include prebuilt static library

Tags: android, android-ndk

I created a static C++ library for testing. It only defines a class, `MyLibrary`, and the constructor `MyLibrary::MyLibrary()`. I built it in qtcreator, and got a `libMyLibrary.a` file, which is a prebuilt static library.

I would like to use this library in an Android project (using the NDK). In a working NDK test project, I therefore added a folder called `inc` at the same level as `jni`, in which I put `libMyLibrary.a` and its corresponding header `mylibrary.h`.

My `Android.mk` is as follows:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := MyLibrary
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../inc/libMyLibrary.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := helloJNI
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := mainActivity.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += inc
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := MyLibrary

LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**The `ndk-build` command compiles without any error.** But my static library is apparently not linked (i.e. it does not appear in `obj/local/armeabi/objs`).

I have tried to include it in my `mainActivity.cpp` file, but even though the header (`mylibrary.h`) is found, the library is not and I cannot create an object as in:

```
MyLibrary test = MyLibrary();
```

What am I doing wrong? I have read tens of similar questions on StackOverflow, but I still don't get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to use this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := helloJNI
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := mainActivity.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/inc/
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/inc/ -lMyLibrary
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

move libMyLibrary.a & mylibrary.h to jni/inc/libMyLibrary.a

Comment: Okay it compiles without errors, as before. How can I ensure that it linked the library? It does not appear in `obj/local/armeabi` either...

Comment: you should check libs\armeabi. is the shared library generated here?

Comment: `libhelloJNI.so` is, but that does not tell me if my static library was linked or not... Note that `MyLibrary` is not used anywhere in the code.

Comment: I think you can use a tool to open library, and check whether relevant API existed. For example, under Linux, you can use command "nm".

Comment: `nm: libhelloJNI.so: no symbols`

Comment: Ho, and also: `warning: skipping incompatible jni/inc//libMyLibrary.a while searching for MyLibrary`

Comment: I will try to compile my static library with ndk-build, if I find a way, and come back here...

Comment: hey, you mentioned "qtcreator". you made a x86 library right? not arm. for android, you have to build an arm library. you have to use NDK to build this static library, otherwise there's a compatibility problem

Comment: If your library is "not used anywhere in the code" then its probable that all functions from it have been omitted from the final .so for efficiency.